# "no user found" 404 on accounts/login using Django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have been using allauth with my Django project since the start and have had no issues. Recently while trying to clean up some code and improve a user search feature it seems my changes break the accounts/login page.

I have been unable to find any fixes online after 2 days of googling and searching through documentation and I am hoping someone with a little more experience might be able to see where my error is.

I have narrowed the cause of the error to a change in a single URL in my users app, which is completely unrelated to allauth.

When I change

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', ProfilePageView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

to

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<str:slug>/', ProfilePageView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

is when I receive the error. Inside my terminal I see `Not Found: /accounts/login/` however in the browser I see `No user found matching the query` which confuses me because I am not sure where this query is coming from.

The main change to my code that I am implementing is in my users.models

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'pk' : self.id,
            'slug' : self.slug,
        }
        return reverse('users:profile', kwargs=kwargs['slug'])
```

which is also giving me a `TypeError: _reverse_with_prefix() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str` but that's another issue (feel free to provide insight on that too if you know).

I thought maybe it was because my search.html was inside the accounts templates directory, so I tried moving it out of there but that did not yield any different results.

I am confused about what this issue is and why changing an unrelated template/url is breaking my allauth pages? it seems to be all of my accounts/ pages, but also the search page that are no longer working, however my home and about pages are functioning. 
Thank you for any and all insight into this issue and please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inadvertently hiding one URL behind another. Your defined `urlpatterns`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<str:slug>/', ProfilePageView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

... are tested in order to find a match. The URL `/search/` matches the first pattern and is routed to the `ProfilePageView` as directed.

The fix is to reverse the order of those definitions, so that `/search/` matches the specific case and `/<slug>/` matches the "fall-through" case:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('<str:slug>/', ProfilePageView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```